# Js. Map inside map

Tags: javascript

In console I see key. But in browser I don’t see key, only element.title.
Want to see in the browser:

```
key 1
title 1
title 2

key 2
title 3
title 4

{Object.entries(bob).map(([key, value]) => {
        return (
          console.log("key", key),
          (<Typography>{key}</Typography>),
          value.map((element) => (
            <Typography key={element.id}>{element.title}</Typography>
          ))
        )
      })}
```

Comment: If you want to see it in the browser then display it (just as you are displaying the title)?

Comment: OP needs to add the respective tag for React.  This is not valid Javascript by itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `bob` looks something like this

```js
const bob = {
  1: [{title: 1}, {title: 2}],
  2: [{title: 3}, {title: 4}]
}
```

You can try out the following snippet

```js
{Object.entries(bob).map(([key, value]) => {
  console.log("key", key);
  return (
    <>
      <Typography>{key}</Typography>
      {value.map((element) => (
        <Typography key={element.id}>{element.title}</Typography>
      ))}
    </>
  )
})}
```

Notice the `<></>` surrounding the key and the value, its called [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html). Since you can't return more than one react node, you need to either surround the return with a valid HTML element/React component or use a fragment